# Windows 2008R2 Server prerequisites to host WCF data services

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I have made a WCF data service and a test client which both run fine on my local machine. The service is hosted on the local IIS on my machine.

Now I'm trying to setup a remote win 2008 R2 server to host the wcf data service, and this is where I run into trouble.

I have first tried to install "WCF Data Services 5.0 for OData V3" from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29306

But I get a "0x80070643 Fatal error during installation"-during installation. I have the log file if that helps.

Now I'm thinking, is it because I need to install "http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services" on the server? I know I did this on my local machine. However this would require me to install Powershell, Visual Studio and NuGet on the server. Is this necessary to get things to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the NuGet packages in your project, then the easiest way is to bin-deploy the WCF DS runtime assemblies. More details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/08/29/odata-101-bin-deploying-wcf-data-services.aspx